# When javascript must be included in the <head> tag and not before </body>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering what situations force you to include javascript in the head section and not before the body ends?

I mean what do the scripts that are **required** to be in the head usually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only document.write() and dependencies between scripts put a requirement on scripts position in the page.

If a script provides methods that can be used anywhere in the `<body>`, it is convenient to put the script in `<head>`, and I believe this is why scripts are often placed in `<head>`.

But I can't think of any reason which would **require** a script to be placed in `<head>`.

Comment: but if you place js files in head, woudn't this force the browser to start requesting these files while continuing to load the page? So this would make the site load slower than if you would put them before the body ends (after page has loaded and rendered), no?

Comment: @Alex, that's mostly right. The scripts will be loaded after the body has rendered, but `onload` wont have fired until *after* the scripts are loaded. The difference is that you likely wont notice any significant changes to the display while the scripts are being loaded, which leads to the **illusion** that the page has finished loading faster.

Comment: The most important **issue** with this (which I happen to address in my answer) is that the user **can't start to interact** with your site right away. **Until** the Javascripts at **the end** are loaded and executed (which can be jQuery+plugins+custom code, 1-300 kB is some cases). The user will report the **UI** to be **unresponsive** and buggy (even tough your code is absolutely error-free). I think this is something **crucial**.

Answer (score 3):

For example they could fire off AJAX requests to fetch JSON data from the server while the rest of the document continues to load.

Comment: but you could have that before `</body>`

Comment: @Alex, sure but the user will have to wait for the entire DOM to be loaded before firing those requests whereas if you put them in the head section they could be fired immediately after this section has been loaded.

Comment: loading js in `head` slows down the page a little. the ajax could wait 1-2 seconds more, since it waits for a response anway :)

Comment: @Alex, it doesn't wait. It fires the request and it continues loading the rest. Of course there could be a slight delay but it is usually smaller compared to network latencies involved when sending AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2):

See the very last paragraph on Quirksmode.org
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Your question is a little broad, so this answer is rather broad as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire JavaScript code before page load event, the only condition which I thinks.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a liberal document language, which is why it's so popular. You are not *required* to place your scripts anywhere in particular.

> I mean what do the scripts that are **required** to be in the head usually do?

Usually you include your libraries/extensions first and foremost in the document. Larger sites don't bother with static HTML pages, instead opting for Content Management Systems. CMSs tend to be highly modular. Allowing the placement of various different content types within various regions of the page. To maintain modularity a simple inline script may be used (especially when using jQuery):

```
<input id="super-special-date-field" type="text" name="ssdf" />
<script type="text/javascript">$('#super-special-date-field').datepicker();</script>
```

This works great assuming jQuery is included in the page, but if it's included at the bottom, this simple script will throw an error.

You *could* make your scripts wait for `document.ready` or `window.onload`, but it's *easier* not to.

Any non-essential scripts can then be placed at the bottom of the page. IMHO if your loading time is under 1s, most people wont be bothered by the load time.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing I usually put in the `<head>` is a basic **early event handling**. So that I catch every event from the very start and execute them when the DOM and proper event handlers are fully loaded.

*to the `<head>`*

```
var earlyEvents = { ... };

// catch every user event, even
// before the DOM is fully loaded
document.onclick = function(event) {
  earlyEvents.register("click", event);
};
```

*`DOMContentLoaded` handler*

```
// execute them when the page is ready
earlyEvents.executeAll();
```

It's important that jQuery may not be available in the `<head>` so `earlyEvents` has to save/copy the event objects, because they're only active during the first execution. You may use a simple loop and [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in `executeAll`.

Facebook does something similar with *[Primer](http://css.dzone.com/articles/how-facebook-jacked-javascript)*